Every weakly compact cardinal $\kappa$ is the $\kappa$th inaccessible cardinal
I'm currently reading Jech's Set Theory book, and in particular, while reading chapter 9, he mentions right after Lemma 9.9 that "We shall prove in Chapter 17 that every weakly compact cardinal $\kappa$ is the $\kappa$th inaccessible cardinal." But while reading chapter 17, I wasn't able to find this claim, at least not explicitly. Does anyone know if the claim is true, and if it is, where I could find it?
Many thanks!

After a quick skim of Chapter 17, I'd guess Jech's talking about Corollary 17.19 (which actually proves much more than just this).

This follows from Corollary 17.19 and the fact that if $\kappa$ is Mahlo then there are $\kappa$ many strongly inaccessible cardinals below it.
